# popupMenuStyle doesn't work when I change parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes

When I change my theme styles

```
<style name="Theme.mystyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.mystyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Not working at all.

```
<style name="PopupMenu.mystyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you have generated custom theme? using http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: Yes, I do. with Theme.AppCompat.Light works well. But no work with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: then just check Androidmanifest, values, values-11, values-14 have same theme applayed

Comment: Also I change in values, values-11,values-14. But I have the same problem.

Comment: in values your theme name is theme.example then same in android manifest app theme, same in v-11, v-14. or just remove style.xml from v-11,v-14 try it

Comment: Thus neither. No work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this generator to get working styles: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Basically when switching to DarkActionBar you need to update your styles to follow:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
   <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
   <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">    
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>    
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>    
</style>
```

Comment: I see this answer is marked correct, but I think this doesn't work for the Overflow menu (just a spinner dropdown).  Did you get the overflow styled?