# Cant change Popup Menu

Tags: android

I defined the following style for my app:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.Base.PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Unfortunately the style for the background of the popup menu (for example in the options menu) does not change at all. The text color is set correclty but the `popupBackground` is totally ignored it stays always white.

So how can i change it to my color?

**EDIT**

Maybe it is a problem that i use a custom toolbar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved after hours of work...

styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" />
```

Comment: Good to hear .Happy coding @Mulgard

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Base.PopupMenu"  parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"> 
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: No it also does not change the popup menus.

Comment: @Mulgard have a look on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381210/no-work-popupmenustyle-when-i-change-parent-style-theme-appcompat-light-darkac

Comment: set parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu" . tell me it works or not ?

Comment: `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` and `parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu"` also arent working. nothing changes the background of my popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

To change the popup menu background color, and thanks to Mulgard's answer, I did the following after adapting the accepted answer's source code a little bit :

So in `activity_main.xml` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/CustomPopupMenu" />
```

And in `styles.xml` :

```
<!-- PopupMenu styles -->
    <style name="CustomPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:background">@color/gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>           
    </style>
```

That's all, it worked for me. I hope this may help you.